# File download using JavaScript and servlet

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, servlets

I have made the servlets both to download and upload the file independently.
Now I need to write a JavaScript code such that as soon as I upload a file a link appears in another HTML page to download that file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AJAX to upload the file and then generate the response to get information about your file to create a link for it. I used the following jquery plugin to implement it.

[Java Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)